# How do you solve this equation: $10 = 2^x + x$?

Tags: logarithms

Is it possible to solve this equation?

\begin{align}
a &= b^x + x \\
a-x &= b^x \\
\log_b(a-x) &= x 
\end{align}

If $a$ and $b$ are known, how do you find $x$?

Comment: Not actually a solution but notice that $f(x)=10-x$ is strictly decreasing, $g(x)=2^{x}$ strictly increasing and $f(2)>g(2)$ and $f(3)<g(3)$ so there exists exactly one solution that is an element of $<2,3>$. I'm really not sure if there is an exact solution.

Comment: Numerical methods will work because the right hand side of your initial equation is increasing (assuming $b \gt 1$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, since the function is monotonically increasing, there is only one real solution. To find the solution for say $10-2^x-x=0$, you can use Newton's method to iterate:
$$x_{n+1} = x_n-\frac{10 - 2^x - x}{2^x\ln 2-1}$$
Alternatively, you could use the Lambert $W$ function to write the solution as:
$$x = 10 -\frac{W(2^{10} \ln(2))}{\ln(2)}$$
To get to this, use the definition: 
$$x = W(x)\exp(W(x))$$
And define $y= 10-x$, and use $W(y)$.